# Flask template does not render after redirection

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask

I am building a very basic CARTO application using Vue JS and Flask. The full code can be found [in this github repository](https://github.com/ramiroaznar/carto-vue-flask).

The application works like this:

1. The user select an option in a modal form and clicks on visualize button. This sends a Vue method called `loadMap` which sends a POST request with a query string (`query` computed property) value as a payload.
2. Then, it redirects the route to another template (`map.html`) and takes a variable (`features`) that is generated from a SQL API call.
3. This variable is a GeoJSON which will populate the data source of the map.

The problem is that after doing the redirection, the map template does not render. This is my Python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    """Displays the homepage."""

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/query', methods=['POST'])
def query():

    data = request.get_json()
    query = data['query']

    return redirect(url_for('map', query=query))

@app.route('/map', methods=['GET'])
def map():

    query = request.args['query']
    url = 'https://ramiroaznar.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q={}&format=geojson'.format(query)

    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get(url)
    features = r.json()

    return render_template('map.html', features=features)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

It looks like the POST and GET call are done correctly, but then the redirection is not launched, so the map is not loaded:

[image]

How can I fix this problem? Is there a more elegant way to achieve this (loading a new website with data from an API call)?

Comment: What does "doesn't render" mean? What exactly do you see?

Comment: The map is not shown. You can check it out in the link I shared.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I have updated the question with more detailed information. Also I have changed the link to glitch, now the app is hosted in github.

Comment: But your app doesn't work at all; nothing happens when you click the button. This is evidently a problem with your JS, and has nothing to do with Flask or redirection.

Comment: I will try to figure out what is wrong then in my js code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was located in my js code. So I fix it moving the map logic to the vue instance. I did also simplify the python code, in order to avoid using two templates. Now the app works, but I should refactor the js code to improve the performance (it takes too long to load) and scalalibility (the map logic should be moved again outside the vue instance). You can find the working example [in this glitch repository](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/4-carto-vuejs-flask?path=server.py:27:23).

The following snippet is my Flask python code...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect

app = Flask(__name__, static_folder='static', template_folder='templates')

@app.route('/')
def home():
    """Displays the homepage."""

    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/data', methods=['GET'])
def data():

    query = request.args.get('query')
    url = 'https://ramiroaznar.carto.com/api/v2/sql?q={}&format=geojson'.format(query)

    session = requests.Session()
    r = session.get(url)
    features = r.json()

    return features

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

... and this is my js code:

```
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [/as-\w+/];

const vm = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        geometryType: 'cities',
        map: false,
        features: {}
    },
    computed: {
        query: function() {
          let table = ''
          if (this.geometryType == 'cities'){
            table = 'ne_10m_populated_places_simple';
          } else {
            table = 'world_borders';
          }
          return `select * from ${table}`
        }
      },
    methods: {
        loadMap: function() {
          this.map = true;

          this.$http.get('/data', {params:  {query: this.query}} ).then(response => {
            this.features = JSON.parse(response.bodyText);
            console.log(this.features);
          }, response => {
            console.log('an error ocurred')
          })
        }
    },
    watch: {

      features: function() {

        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
          container: 'map',
          style: carto.basemaps.voyager,
          center: [10.151367,51.172455],
          zoom: 2,
          scrollZoom: false
          });

        const nav = new mapboxgl.NavigationControl({ showCompass: false });
        map.addControl(nav, 'top-left');

        carto.setDefaultAuth({
            username: 'cartovl',
            apiKey: 'default_public'
        });

        console.log(this.features);
        const source = new carto.source.GeoJSON(this.features);
        const viz = new carto.Viz();
        const layer = new carto.Layer('layer', source, viz);
        layer.addTo(map, 'watername_ocean');
    }

  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a redirect try to render the template.

```
@app.route('/query', methods=['POST'])
def query():
    data = request.get_json()
    query = data['query']
    return render_template('map.html', query=query)
```

Hope this helps :P